# Store UUID of discover peripheral in CoreBluetooth LE iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried below code to store UUID of discovered devices to Array  and then select UUID in  this array to connect but it not run.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    NSLog (@"Discovered peripheral: %@", [peripheral name]);
    [foundArray addObject:peripheral.name];

    NSLog (@"UUID peripheral: %@", [peripheral UUID]);

    CFUUIDRef uuid = [peripheral UUID];
    [discoverUUIDArray addObject: (__bridge id)(uuid)];
    NSLog(@"Before = %@", uuid);

    NSLog (@"peripheral services before connected: %@", [peripheral services]);

    NSLog(@"adversting data %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[advertisementData description]]);

    self.activePeripheral = peripheral;

    NSLog(@"foundArray is %@", foundArray);
    NSLog(@"discoverUUIDArray is %@", discoverUUIDArray);
    [self.tblFound reloadData];

}
```

Then I load these Discover device to tableview, when user select device to connect, my app hangs.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.manager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        NSLog(@"You selected %@ to connect",[foundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        CFUUIDRef uuidGet = (__bridge CFUUIDRef) [discoverUUIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"UUID is %@",[discoverUUIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        [self.manager connectPeripheral:[discoverUUIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] options:nil];

    }
}
```

When select device to connect, it shows error :

```
[__NSCFType state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d70950
2013-12-25 15:17:40.699 TestPeripheral[213:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d70950'
```

discoverUUIDArray store UUID of discover device. I don't know why. Please give me some advices . Thanks so much.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  Where do you assign to `self.manager`?

Comment: It looks like `self.manager.state` is crashing. Where are you allocating and initialising your `self.state` property?

Answer (score 3):

`CFUUIDRef uuid = [peripheral UUID];` is deprecated in iOS7, 
use the `peripheral.identifier` which as an `NSUUID` to store in the array if you want

if the intent is to store the `UUID's` for future retrieval,keep it in the `NSUserDefaults` instead of a runtime array

Answer (score 0):

You can create an NSMutableArray to store a list of all discovered devices, then use this list to populate a UITableView and connect, if selected by a user.

e.g.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if (![localName isEqual:@""]) {
        [self.BTLEDevices addObject:peripheral];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"BLEDeviceList";
    CBPeripheral *peripheral = [self.BTLEDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = peripheral.name;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CBPeripheral *peripheral = [self.BTLEDevices objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row integerValue]];  
    peripheral.delegate = self;
    [self.BTLECentralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

Don't forget to create the UITableView object and add it to your view, also I've left out the other CBPeripheral methods.  Hope that helps.